# Ignoring changes for Azure Firewall rules in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm setting up an azure firewall rule and I wish to set ignore changes on the source addresses. Can anyone help me with the correct syntax.

Using hashicorp/azurerm v2.99.0.

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_nat_rule_collection" "FwRules" {
  name                          = "NATRules"
  azure_firewall_name           = var.afw_name
  resource_group_name           = var.rg_afw_name
  priority                      = 100
  action                        = "Dnat"

  rule {
    name                    = "Rule1"
    description             = "Allow Traffic"
    source_addresses        = []
    destination_ports       = ["3389"]
    destination_addresses   = [var.public_ip]
    translated_port         = "3389"
    translated_address      = azurerm_network_interface.vm1.private_ip_address
    protocols               = ["TCP"]
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      rules[0].source_addresses,
    ]
  }
}
```

I've also tried `rule.Rule1.source_addresses`

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in my environment getting the below error.

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      rules[0].source_addresses,
    ]
  }
```

[image]

**Solution: You should use rule[0] not rules[0].**

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      rule[0].source_addresses
      
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried using rule instead of rules and now get the error.

│ Error: Cannot index a set value
│
│   on main.tf line 535, in resource "azurerm_firewall_nat_rule_collection" "afw_nat_rules":
│  535:         rule[0].source_addresses
│
│ Block type "rule" is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if" clause.

Comment: Please provide rest of your code to troubleshoot more.

Comment: I have done further research and found the following comment on a github issue
[link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26359#issuecomment-1064652196)

I think it explains the limitations quite well. For now as the rule is relatively static I have moved to just ignoring the whole rule rather than just the source ips. 

`
    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        rule
      ]
    }
`

Thank you @RahulKumarShaw-MT for your help.

Comment: FYI you really need to include properly-formatted text when providing code, output, errors, etc. and not images of text. Please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is really important.